# How to get nearest 1000 to given number using jquery?

Tags: jquery, rounding

How to get nearest 1000 to given a number. I have written like this.

```
function roundToNearest(numToRound, numToRoundTo) {
    numToRoundTo = 1 / (numToRoundTo);

    return Math.round(numToRound * numToRoundTo) / numToRoundTo;
}
alert(roundToNearest(2499,1000));
```

I am getting correct results but if it is 1500 i need to get 1000 only.

```
ex: 1100=>1000,
1400=>1000,
1500=>1000,
1600=>2000,
2000=>2000
```

But using above function i am getting 2000 for 1500 instead of 1000. How to get 1000 if the number is 1500?

Comment: So, to be clear, `1500` should round to `1000` and `1501` should round to `2000`, is that right?

Comment: Because the nearest whole number to 1/2 is the next number up - ie it rounds up.  Why would you expect 1500 to give 1000?

Comment: yes its right @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: And are you sure that 499 is the same a s 0  to your users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want `1500` to round to `1000` and `1501` to round to `2000` you're simply moving the default rounding point up by one. In which case you can just subtract one from the value to be rounded. So long as you're only rounding whole, positive integers this should not cause any issues. Try  this:

```js
function roundToNearest(numToRound, numToRoundTo) {
  numToRoundTo = 1 / (numToRoundTo);
  return Math.round((numToRound - 1) * numToRoundTo) / numToRoundTo;
}

[2, 1100, 1500, 1501, 1600, 2000].forEach(function(v) {
  console.log(v, roundToNearest(v, 1000));
});
```